# Has C++/WinRT or WinRT/ABI a CRTP "feature" with _declspec(novtable)?

Tags: c++-winrt

Coming from ATL(Active Template Library) there is a coclass an abstract base class and hence it is secure to tag the coclass with ATL_NO_VTABLE ( _declspec(novtable)). So you can use only the Microsoft C++ compiler to use the ATL classes. Has C++/winRT or WinRT/ABI such a CRTP-"feature" also for other C++ compilers ? And if, how does it work ?

Answer (score 1):

`__declspec(novtable)` is an implementation detail, unrelated to the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). It is handled in C++/WinRT like pretty much any other platform specific implementation in virtually any other C or C++ library: By use of preprocessor macros. You'll find the following in *<base.h>*:

> ```cpp
> #if defined(_MSC_VER)
> ...
> #define WINRT_NOVTABLE __declspec(novtable)
> ...
> #else
> ...
> #define WINRT_NOVTABLE
> ...
> #endif
> ```

The respective base types in namespace `winrt::impl` are appropriately tagged `WINRT_NOVTABLE`.

Comment: Please just use __declspec(novtable) directly if you need it (or define your own macro). The C++/WinRT macros are not meant for public use.